# Matching API path with Swagger API path

Tags: python, python-3.x, swagger

Good day,

How can I map the following API path provided by user to the available path in the server using python?

For example, user provides the following API path:

```
/tables/123/fields
```

which matches the following path in server:

```
/tables/{table_id}/fields
```

where {table_id} is a required field.

So how can I know if the user's path matches the system's path?
Another example is as below:

```
user's provide path: /pet/111
system's path: /pet/{petId}
```

I have provided a argument to store the path and I need to match it with the server's path to get the operationId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i do notice that there's a workaround we can do. By treating the {table_id} as a str.format, extracting the values from user's path, store it into the system's path.

Then compare the 2 url to check if it is the same. If yes, then get the operationalId